# Javascript For Loop Not Appending into Div as Expected?

Tags: javascript

Im not really sure what Im doing wrong here. I essentially check if any of the elements values are empty, and if they are it started to iterate through them.

Once it iterates it appends the id's of the elements that are empty into the div. Or at least thats what I expected it to do. Any help? Thanks!

```
<script>

   function validate(){
       var username = document.getElementById("username");
       var name = document.getElementById("name");
       var phone = document.getElementById("phone-number");
       var email = document.getElementById("email");
       var password = document.getElementById("password");
       var passwordc = document.getElementById("password-confirmation");

       var array = [username, name, phone, email, password, passwordc];

       if(username.value == "" || name.value == "" || phone.value == "" || email.value == "" || password.value == "" || passwordc.value == ""){
           document.getElementById('required-field-error').innerHTML = "The following must not be blank: ";

           for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++);{
               if(array[i].value == ""){
               document.getElementById('required-field-error').innerHTML += " array[i].id ";
               }
               else{document.getElementById('required-field-error').innerHTML += "";}
           }

       }
       else{
           document.getElementById('required-field-error').innerHTML = "";
       }
   }


</script>
```

Comment: `" array[i].id "` means _literally_ the string `" array[i].id "`. Don’t use quotes here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You terminated the for loop independently and hence you are getting out of bond index. And also as pointer by 'Xufox' that is literal string.
Find the corrected script below:

```
  <script>
       function validate(){
           var username = document.getElementById("username");
           var name = document.getElementById("name");
           var phone = document.getElementById("phone-number");
           var email = document.getElementById("email");
           var password = document.getElementById("password");
           var passwordc = document.getElementById("password-confirmation");

           var array = [username, name, phone, email, password, passwordc];

           if(username.value == "" || name.value == "" || phone.value == "" || email.value == "" || password.value == "" || passwordc.value == ""){
               document.getElementById('required-field-error').innerHTML = "The following must not be blank: ";

               for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                   if(array[i].value == ""){
                   document.getElementById('required-field-error').innerHTML += " " + array[i].id;
                   }
                   else{document.getElementById('required-field-error').innerHTML += "";}
               }

           }
           else{
               document.getElementById('required-field-error').innerHTML = "";
           }
       }        
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your code by doing something like this instead:

```
function validate() {
  const requiredFields = ['username', 'name', 'phone-number', 'email', 'password', 'password-confirmation'];
  const missingFields = requiredFields.filter(requiredFieldStr => {
    return !document.getElementById(requiredFieldStr).value;
  });
  const requiredFieldError = document.getElementById('required-field-error');
  if (missingFields.length > 0) {
    requiredFieldError.textContent =
      "The following must not be blank: " + missingFields.join('');
  } else requiredFieldError.textContent = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your requirement exactly.
But if you use [JQuery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) that will simplify the things for you.